# How to access hidden RecyclerView items?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-recyclerview

I tried searching this problem but couldn't find a proper solution.

Basically, I have a layout containing a RecyclerView, with 6 items.

Of the 6 items 5 are visible on screen. 6th is hidden.

Now on performing an action (drag and drop here), I modify the contents within each item. This is happening.

However, only for the visible items.

When I scroll down on 6th item after performing the action, it doesn't manifest the change. Only the visible 5 do.

I used `getChildCount()` method of recycler view within the adapter and it shows the value as 5 (not 6). I debugged and found it is currently considering the number of children as those visible on screen.

If I scroll down a little, as such a below part of 1st item and upper part of 6th item is visible, and perform the action to modify all item contents - it works!

I think using LinearLayoutManager is a solution as it returns the itemCount as 6 in any situation but can't understand how to use to access the item/child of the RecyclerView.

I deliberately tried to access and modify 6th item of RecyclerView using the `getChildAt(5)` and I got a `NullPointerException` since RV is not identifying that item due to it's invisibility on the screen.

Also, the modification in item contents, on performing an action, is being performed with the code typed inside the RV adapter, in custom methods, not the overridden methods of the RecyclerView Adapter like `onBindViewHolder(...)` by obtaining reference to the view and accessing their subviews with the help of `getChildAt()` .

I doubt if code is needed, however if needed, please let know. I am using custom DragListener class where I am accessing the views, subviews of each RecyclerView item and modifying the data.

How shall I access all items (visible and hidden) of RV and modify them in one go?

Comment: I guess it is obvious as the legal way to access an item and modify is through OnBindViewHolder(...). If correct, then how shall I get it to work with OnDragListener methods? Because if I use OnDragListener inside Adapter, for some functionality, I cannot then get it to coordinate with Adapter methods at the same time. I hope I am clear...

Comment: Do you called `notifyItemChanged(position)` for that item.

Comment: Sorry Qamar but I don't see much of a connection between my problem and this method. Maybe you must elaborate and make me understand by addressing my problem

Comment: Please clarify your question so that people stop guessing wrong. Use less words to explain. Do you need to change views or data pubulated for that invisible item views?

Comment: In that case you can confirm first. Sorry, but I wanted to provide complete picture for a perfect solution. Maybe read it once slowly, word to word, whenever time permits.  I want to modify the data within item.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot modify the items of a RecyclerView by manipulating it's childs directly. Instead you have to apply all changes by changing the items in your adapter.

Say you have a title and this title now changes after reordering. Then you have to change the titles of all elements within your adapter. Finally you have to trigger those items to be redrawn.

The RecyclerView has its name for a reasons. only the visible items (plus one) are created and after that whenever one item disappears, another it is reused for any newly appearing item. That's why it works if you slightly move your view upwards. now you have six items visible.

For sufficiently large data sets the child count is much lower than the number of items that form the basis of the shown data. And thus you cannot change the data by using the children of the RecyclerView.